# ADB not detect Sony Xperia Z3 Compact (android 5.0.2)

Tags: android, debugging, adb, android-5.0-lollipop, sony-xperia

ADB and Android Studio not detect my device in debugging mode. I work on Windows 7 x64 Pro with latest SDK platform tools.

I tried almost all different device configuration - plug in in MTP and MSC mode, revoke authorisation, install sony and modified generic drivers and any other tips - with no success.

Anyone has any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: did you  enable the developer options?

Comment: At start - without enable developer options I can not revoke authorisation which is under developer mode...

Comment: install http://pdanet.co/ pdanet on your system. device should be connected while installing. hope this will install all drivers

Comment: Thanks @Qadir Hussain. I tried install this software but PdaNet+ had also problem with install drivers. I installed separetely Sony drivers with added entries in sa0111adb.inf file and PdaNet+ starts but with warning "Wrong WinUsb pipe found". ADB still not detecting device. No idea.

Comment: One more comment. On Win 7 Home 32bit device was found without any problems and drivers were installed automaticaly. I think it could be a wider problem with USB ports. Today I had also problem with connecting hard drive on usb (USB to ATA/ATAPI Bridge drivers not found). Also couple weeks ago I tried to connect mouse with bluetooth connector without success. So I will looking for solution related to this.

Answer (score 6):

Try installing Sony PC Companion. This should install all of the necessary drivers for communication with adb:

http://support.sonymobile.com/global-en/tools/pc-companion/

Comment: I tried it but without success. Also PdaNet+ advised by @Qadir Hussain did not give any positive results. On Win 8.1 I do not have any problems. I will try also on Win 7 Home to check what is going on with drivers.

Comment: Ok I see. Now that you have PC Companion installed try opening device manager. There will probably see your device in the list right away saying that the driver is not working correctly. From here you should be able to just click on update driver. Give it a shot and let me know if that works.

Comment: The problem was that automatically or manual updates of drivers did not give any positive resutls. If I picked up drivers from the list or I pointed correct *.inf file, device not work properly (or not install it at all). As I supposed problem was not with device driver but with windows driver mangement. Finally I resolved this problem what I will describe in next post. Thanks @Robert - Sony.

Answer (score 3):

After all, without success, the device was found in Devices Manager but with question mark, and the driver was not found.

So I need to download the driver from Sony at

http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/xperia-z3-compact-driver/

and manually update the driver.

So, after that, the device was recognized in Android Studio.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After couple of days of fight with drivers I found solution and applied it with success. As I supposed and wrote in one comment above, the problem was not in adb drivers but with drivers (esspecially usb driver) installation. Shortly, to properly install drivers and run adb I need to clean cache drivers and rescan computer to rebuild driver information. I found description of similar problem here:

[Windows 7: Unable to install any USB devices](http://www.sevenforums.com/hardware-devices/86442-unable-install-any-usb-devices.html#post1014226)

Also I rewrite solution here for anyone who will have this kind of problem:

> Here's the solution for the ones who might have this problem:
>   This worked for me in Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit!
>   You must have all administrator privileges!
>
> 1- Open Windows Explorer
>
> 2- Go to C:/Windows/System32/DriverStore
>
> You will have a couple of folders and files.
>   You will have *.dat files and other file named: infcache.1
>
> 3- Right click every file (dont touch the folders!) and choose properties.
>
> 4- go to security tab
>
> 5- click Edit
>
> 6- choose your account and check the box: full control (see ss)
>
> 7- Click ok.
>
> 8- Repeat to every file
>
> 9- Select all the files (*.dat and infcache.1)
>
> 10- Press shift+del
>
> 11- Press OK.
>
> 12- Now, go to C:Windows/System32/Driver Store/File Repository/
>
> 13- Search for folder named usbstor.inf
>
> 14- Open it (if you have more than one, choose the most recent)
>
> 15- Copy "usbstor.inf" and "usbstor.PNF"
>
> 16- Paste those two files to C:/Windows/inf
>
> 17- Reboot your pc and voilla! :b
>
> If Windows doesnt install them automatically go to device manager, uninstall all unknown devices and the ones with the yellow exclamation mark, then click in "check to see if there is any hardware changes"
>
> Now, Windows will install all your hardware successfully

After making all of this steps computer found automatically Sony Xperia Z3 Compact device, installed all drivers and adb show my device on the list. Finally it works well right now.

I hope it help if somoene will have simmilar problem in the future.